# Mudar cor de fundo do plugin multiselect do jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Pessoal estou usando o plugin multiselect do JQuery https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/multiselect/.

Ocorre que ele está me gerando duas dificuldades.

A primeira dificuldade é com  CSS: Preciso alterar as cores que ele coloca nas caixas de seleção e nas fontes. Já procurei até onde fica isso e não achei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A outra dificuldade é com JQuery mesmo. Preciso criar uma função que, ao clicar na primeira opção, ou seja, indiferente, os demais campos são desativados para escolha. E, caso clicado novamente libera os demais campos. Ainda, se algum campo que não seja o indiferente for selecionado, então o indiferente se desabilita.  Ou então achar  onde eu consigo alterar o texto que aparece na caixa de SELECIONE para cada uma dos select's.

jquery.multiselect.css

```
.ui-multiselect { padding:2px 0 2px 4px; text-align:left }
.ui-multiselect span.ui-icon { float:right }
.ui-multiselect-single .ui-multiselect-checkboxes input { position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; left:-9999px; }
.ui-multiselect-single .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { padding:5px !important }

.ui-multiselect-header { margin-bottom:3px; padding:3px 0 3px 4px }
.ui-multiselect-header ul { font-size:0.9em }
.ui-multiselect-header ul li { float:left; padding:0 10px 0 0 }
.ui-multiselect-header a { text-decoration:none }
.ui-multiselect-header a:hover { text-decoration:underline }
.ui-multiselect-header span.ui-icon { float:left }
.ui-multiselect-header li.ui-multiselect-close { float:right; text-align:right; padding-right:0 }

.ui-multiselect-menu { display:none; padding:3px; position:absolute; z-index:10000; text-align: left }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes { position:relative /* fixes bug in IE6/7 */; overflow-y:scroll }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { cursor:default; display:block; border:1px solid transparent; padding:3px 1px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes label input { position:relative; top:1px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li { clear:both; font-size:0.9em; padding-right:3px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li.ui-multiselect-optgroup-label { text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-bottom:1px solid }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li.ui-multiselect-optgroup-label a { display:block; padding:3px; margin:1px 0; text-decoration:none }

/* remove label borders in IE6 because IE6 does not support transparency */
* html .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { border:none }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="buscaImovel"><br />
  <h1 >Pesquise pelo imóvel que deseja</h1>
  QUERO COMPRAR E QUERO VENDER<br />
  <form action="busca.php"  method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="tipos" name="tipos">
    <input type="hidden" id="bairros" name="bairros">

    <div class="camposBusca">
      <?php  $tiposImoveis = $tiposDao->pesquisaTipos(); ?>
      <label class="labelPequeno">Tipo</label>
      <br />
      <select multiple="multiple" id="tipo" name="tipo[]" size="1" required>
        <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
        <?php
             if ($tiposImoveis == null) {
                 echo "<option value=''>Não há tipo cadastrado ainda!</option>";
             } else {
               foreach ($tiposImoveis as $tipoImovel) {
                   echo "<option value='".$tipoImovel->getIdTipos()."'>".$tipoImovel->getNome()."</option>";
               }
             }
           ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="camposBusca">
      <?php  $bairrosImoveis = $imoveisDao->pesquisaBairros("Muriaé"); ?>
      <label class="labelPequeno">Bairro</label>
      <br />
      <select multiple="multiple" id="bairro" name="bairro[]" size="1" required>
        <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
        <?php
             if ($bairrosImoveis == null) {
                 echo "<option value=''>Não há tipo cadastrado ainda!</option>";
             } else {
               foreach ($bairrosImoveis as $bairrosImovel) {
                   echo "<option value='".$bairrosImovel."'>".$bairrosImovel."</option>";
               }
             }
           ?>
      </select>      
    </div>
    <div class="camposBusca">
      <button>Buscar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div style="height:15px;"></div>
  <div class="alternativaEscolha"> <a href="buscaAvancada.php">
    <label class="labelGrande" style="background-color:#CCC;">Busca Avançada</label>
    </a> </div>
  <div class="alternativaEscolha"> 
    <!--abrir popUp--> 
    <a href="buscaCodigo.php">
    <label class="labelGrande" style="background-color:#CCC;">Busca por Código</label>
    </a> </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
  $(function(){
      $("#tipo").multiselect();
      $("#bairro").multiselect();
  });

  $("#tipo").multiselect().change(function() {
      $("#tipos").val($("#tipo").multiselect().val());    
  })
  $("#bairro").multiselect().change(function() {
      $("#bairros").val($("#bairro").multiselect().val());    
  })
```

Até onde deu para ir:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    for (i = 0; i < $(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes").length; i++) {  
      $ui = $(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes");
      $indiferente = $ui.find("[title=Indiferente]");
      $indiferente.prop("checked", true);
      $ui.find("input").change(function(){
        if($(this).attr("title") != "Indiferente" && this.checked){
            $indiferente.prop("checked", false); //desmarco indiferente se algum
                                                //outro for selecionado
        }
        if(!$ui.find("input:checked").length){ //se nenhum input estiver marcado
            $indiferente.prop("checked",true); //marco indiferente

        }
      })

      $indiferente.change(function(){                 //quando indiferente mudar
        if(this.checked){                             //se estiver marcado
            $ui.find("input").not("[title=Indiferente]").prop("checked", false);                       
                                                      //desmarco outros
        }           
      })

      $("#ui-multiselect-tipo-option-0").click(); $("#ui-multiselect-bairro-option-0").click();

    }
  })



  $(function(){
      $("#tipo").multiselect();
      $("#bairro").multiselect();
  });


</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $(".fechar").click(function() {
    $(".buscaCodigo").hide();
    $(".fechar").hide();
  });

  $(".alternativaEscolha").click(function() {
    $(".buscaCodigo").show();
    $(".fechar").show();
  });  

});
</script>

<div class="fechar">
  <img src="_img/btn-close.png" style="width:50px;" />
</div>

<div class="buscaCodigo">
   <form action="busca.php" method="post">

     <input type="hidden" name="acao"  value="buscaCodigo" />

     <label>Código</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio" id="codigo"  name="codigo" required />

     <input type="submit">

   </form> 
</div>

<div class="buscaImovel"><br />
  <h1 class="h1Centralizado">Pesquise pelo imóvel que deseja</h1>

  <div class="divBusca">

  <form action="busca.php"  method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="buscaPrincipal">

    <div class="camposBusca">
      <?php  $tiposImoveis = $tiposDao->pesquisaTipos(); ?>
      <label class="labelPequeno">Tipo</label>
      <br />
      <select multiple="multiple" id="tipo" name="tipo[]" size="1" required>
        <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
        <?php
             if ($tiposImoveis == null) {
                 echo "<option value=''>Não há tipo cadastrado ainda!</option>";
             } else {
               foreach ($tiposImoveis as $tipoImovel) {

                   echo "<option value='".$tipoImovel->getIdTipos()."'>".$tipoImovel->getNome()."</option>";
               }
             }
           ?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="camposBusca">
      <?php  $bairrosImoveis = $imoveisDao->pesquisaBairros("Muriaé"); ?>
      <label class="labelPequeno">Bairro</label>
      <br />
      <select multiple="multiple" id="bairro" name="bairro[]" size="1" required>
        <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
        <?php
             if ($bairrosImoveis == null) {
                 echo "<option value=''>Não há tipo cadastrado ainda!</option>";
             } else {
               foreach ($bairrosImoveis as $bairrosImovel) {
                   echo "<option value='".$bairrosImovel."'>".$bairrosImovel."</option>";
               }
             }
           ?>
      </select>      
    </div>

    <div class="camposBusca" style="height:55px; width:55px; margin-bottom:0;">
      <input type="submit" style="background-image: url(_img/pesquisar.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;" value="Pesquisar"  />
    </div>

  </form>
  </div>

  <div style="height:15px;"></div>

  <div class="alternativaEscolha">
    <a href="buscaAvancada.php">
      <label class="labelGrande" style="background-color:#CCC;">Busca Avançada</label>
    </a> 
  </div>

  <div class="alternativaEscolha"> 
    <!--abrir popUp--> 
        <label class="labelGrande" style="background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF">Busca por Código</label> 
  </div>

</div>

<script>
  $("#tipo").multiselect().change(function() {
      $("#tipos").val($("#tipo").multiselect().val());    
  })
  $("#bairro").multiselect().change(function() {
      $("#bairros").val($("#bairro").multiselect().val());    
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Oi Carlos, você poderia colocar o seu código fonte (css, html e js) aqui para que possamos ver como está sendo customizado o seu select?

Comment: sim, coloquei. Mas pode ser visto também em http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mudar a cor do fundo, você pode adicionar isso ao seu css:

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
     background: blue !important /* escolha a cor que você quiser */
}
```

E quanto ao caso do indiferente, eu aconselho você a melhorar a identificação dos elementos, mas se você quiser que funcione exatamente da forma como está o seu html, pode usar o seguinte script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $ui = $(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes").first()
  $indiferente = $ui.find("[title=Indiferente]");
  $ui.find("input").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr("title") != "Indiferente" && this.checked){
        $indiferente.prop("checked", false); //desmarco indiferente se algum
                                            //outro for selecionado
    }
    if(!$ui.find("input:checked").length){ //se nenhum input estiver marcado
        $indiferente.prop("checked",true); //marco indiferente

    }
  })
  $indiferente.change(function(){                 //quando indiferente mudar
    if(this.checked){                             //se estiver marcado
        $ui.find("input").not("[title=Indiferente]").prop("checked", false);                       
                                                  //desmarco outros
    }           
  })
})
```

Comment: Bom, sobre o css obrigado, vou separar cada um e dar backgrounds-color diferentes. mas quanto ao JQuery acho que vai ficar mais fácil receber com o php e verificar se existe a opção 'Indiferente'. Se houver, pesquiso de todos, Vai ficar muito extenso adicionar função verificar o contrario também: caso nenhum item esteja selecionado, então o indiferente fica desabilitado. Isso vai ficar muito confuso.

Comment: Acabei de fazer uma edição, agora se algum outro checkbox que não seja o "Indiferente" for selecionado, o "Indiferente" é desabilitado

Comment: Isso vai ficar uma coisa meio que sem lógica. Imagina a cena; Você marcou um que não seja indiferente, nesse momento, indiferente é desabilitado. Ok. Marcou os 'n' próximos não indiferentes. Então, e se você desmarcar todos os não indiferentes marcados, quando desmarcar o ultimo, o indiferente deve ser habilitado novamente. Isso aí parece meio que sem sentido e surreal. Não?

Comment: Bem, nem tanto. Para você deixar dessa maneira é só colocar o atributo checked por padrão no input do indiferente. Depende de como você está projetando o sistema, tudo pode ter sentido nesse mundo x)
Eu particularmente até gostei do select assim

Comment: Mas se eu colocar o atributo checked por padrão no input do indiferente isso não vai garantir que ao deselecionar todos os Não Indeferentes selecionados, que ele se habilite novamente. Vai?

Comment: Bem, nesse caso não vale a pena utilizar o disabled. Podemos fazer isso apenas com o checked. Testa as últimas modificações que eu fiz, e me diz se elas são aplicáveis ao seu caso

Comment: Na verdade, ficou imensamente melhor do que eu esperava. Agora vou estudar o que você fez para eu aprender isso direito. Muito obrigado. Agora, não querendo abusar da ajuda do amigo, certa vez ví um efeito em um site que não me lembro mais aonde uma div ia aparecendo aos poucos do topo à base dela. Muito bacana. Já ví alguns efeitos na net mas nada igual ao que ví. Você conhece esse efeito? Sabe como eu consigo implementar?

Comment: Bem, você pode usar os efeitos de animação do próprio css para fazer isso. Não cabe a essa pergunta essa explicação, se você tiver mesmo interesse, faça uma outra pergunta para facilitar quando outros usuários tiverem a mesma dúvida

Comment: Esta correto. Vou fazer a pergunta!

Comment: Ainda sobre o css, não consegui alterar 3 coisas no selelct ainda: 1) A cor da borda, 2) A cor de fundo laranja 3) A cor das setinhas. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Conforme nova imagem alterada na pergunta

Comment: Voltando ao caso do indiferente, será que tem uma forma de, adicionar 1 opção ao contador de opções marcadas? Porque na hora de submeter o formulário, como ainda não foi clicado nenhuma opção embora o indiferente esteja marcado ele não esta sendo computado ainda e o formulário não é despachado. Algum recurso nesse caso?

Comment: Tenta com isso:
 $("#ui-multiselect-tipo-option-0").click(); $("#ui-multiselect-bairro-option-0").click()

Comment: Coloca dentro do bloco $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: LF Ziron, já esta dentro do bloco. a ideia anterior até que fez aparecer lá "1 Selecionado" Mas o form ainda não dispara. Só se realmente eu clicar em algum item que vai. Seria interessante se desse para a aparecer de cara "indiferente" e já desse para enviar o formulário

Comment: Não esqueça de desmarcar indiferente como padrão no seu html, ou senão o código vai desmarcá-lo. Eu estive olhando aqui, e você também vai ter que adicionar após o código anterior: $("#bairro").multiselect("refresh"); $("#tipo").multiselect("refresh");

Comment: nem assim. Vou colocar como esta lá no fim da pergunta. Dá uma olhada faz\endo favor onde estou errando?